# Long running UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server

I want to update some values in a table but the query takes more than two hours and it continues to run. Is there anything obviously wrong with my query?

```
 UPDATE tblQuestionnaires
 SET    nAddBy = ( SELECT   tblanswers.nolduserid
                   FROM     tblAnswers
                   WHERE    tblanswers.strOldMobileModelQuestionairenumber 
                          = tblQuestionnaires.strQuestionnaireCode
                   GROUP BY tblanswers.nolduserid ,
                            tblanswers.strOldMobileModelQuestionairenumber
                 )
 WHERE  tblQuestionnaires.nId BETWEEN 610815 AND 614988
```

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY` in your sub-query?

Comment: because in tblanswers there is repeating values of nolduserid and old mobilemodelquestionairenumber

Comment: and if i not used group by query give me error that its return more than one value

Comment: try without grouping and use `select top 1 tblanswers.nolduserid`

Comment: hmm i did with top 1 and still running

Comment: How long does it take to run your subquery without the update statement for the same data sample?

Comment: within 10 seconds data shows

Comment: Are you getting locks? Check sp_who2 when running the update statement

Comment: Has it even stopped after 2hours? If not, there might be something blocking the update process, might be a lock on the concerned table by another process.

Comment: no my spid for this query is runnable

Comment: as it is only 4000ish rows, you could try updating by running your subquery and matching to tblQuestionnaires in Excel using VLOOKUP,then using the matches to write a direct update, as a process of elimination to just to see if it works any quicker?

Comment: Are there any indexes on the `tblQuestionnaires` table that also need to be updated?

Comment: no actually i need sql query solution for this

Comment: understood that you would need it long-term, but can be useful just to try an alternative to rule out problems with the query vs. problems with the table

Comment: yes you are right i need to update rows in parts because there is 4000 rows to need to update i have to break query with different rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it that way means that the subquery in the SET clause is likely being executed for every questionnaire.  As a general rule, I like to build the query as a select that outputs the id of the row you want to update, as well as the calculated value that you need.  For your case, it'd be something like this:

```
select  q.nId,
        a.nolduserid
    from tblQuestionnaires q
    join tblAnswers a on
        a.strOldMobileModelQuestionairenumber = q.strQuestionnaireCode
    where
        q.nId between 610815 and 614988
    group by a.nolduserid, q.nId
```

Then change that query into an update:

```
update q
    set 
        nAddBy = a.nolduserid
    from tblQuestionnaires q
    join tblAnswers a on
        a.strOldMobileModelQuestionairenumber = q.strQuestionnaireCode
    where
        q.nId between 610815 and 614988
    group by a.nolduserid, q.nId
```

Please note that I haven't tested this (I don't have your data), but this should work a little better.